# Post request fires alternatively

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app wherein I send data through an HTTP POST request to a PHP server. But, the problem is that the post request fires alternately; (for example; the first time, it sends the data to the server. The second time, it doesn't. This continues.)

**Here's my code:**

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            // post the request
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();
            // handle the response
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("status code",String.valueOf(status));
            if (status != 200) {
                Log.e("ServerUtilities","post failed . status 200");
                throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            if (conn != null) {
                InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
                String line;
                String serverResponseMessage="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    serverResponseMessage += line;
                }
                Log.e("serverResponse",serverResponseMessage);
                reader.close();
                response.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            }
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but if your `url` is a domain name and not the specific IP/PORT of a server it might be that the domain is hooked to a load balancer which alternates incoming requests between two servers.

Comment: it is an IP address which connects to my local server.@CeilingGecko

Comment: Did you debug the code to check if the data are actually being sent? Maybe its a probelm in the recieving end?

Comment: yeah. I checked it. it even returns value, But, alternatively.@EvripidisDrakos

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below code. It worked fine with me.

```java
public class ServiceHandler
{

  static String response = null;
  public final static int GET = 1;
  public final static int POST = 2;

  public ServiceHandler()
  {

  }


  public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method)
  {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
  }


  public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
      HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        if (method == POST) {
          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

          if (params != null) {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
          }

          Log.d("before httpclient","execute") ;

          httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          Log.d("after httpclient", "execute") ;
        } else if (method == GET) {

            if (params != null) {
              String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
              url += "?" + paramString;
            }

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        Log.d("response", response) ;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

  }
}
```

Comment: The imports are missing. This might well lead to problems. When posting code, it should be runnable ;)

Comment: @Nikesh, Sorry. But could you please tell me why my program fires the post request alternatively

Comment: If you are working with Android Studeio then authomatically all the libraries will get imported. If its Eclipse then use CTRL + SHIFT + O to import all at once